# Ajaxified link in MVC3/JQuery not working in IE8 (missing header)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, internet-explorer-8, header

Consider the following code (it is based on a default EMPTY MVC3 project created in visual web developer express 2010sp1):

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="main">@RenderBody()</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index method of HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "partial";
        return PartialView();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "full";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myLink').click(function () {
            $.post(this.href, function (result) {
                $('#main').html(result);
                alert(result);
            });
            return false;
            //$('#main').load(this.href);
            //return false;
        });
    });
</script>

HomeController index. @ViewBag.Message
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { id = "myLink" } );
```

The problem is that in IE8 when the myLink link is clicked, it doesn't update the main div with only the partial html from Index.cshtml but the complete html including the layout. Ofcourse it works fine in FF, I mean why shouldn't it right? It seems Request.IsAjaxRequest() always evaluates to false in IE8. I understand that it is a result of a header `X-Requested-With` not being attached to a request in IE8. I don't have a lot of experience with web development -- is this a common issue and what is the (best) way to solve this?

UPDATE:

Yesterday I got it working normally in IE8, but when I tried it again this morning, the same problem was back. Now I don't think it has anything to do with the settings in IE8 anymore as I restored the settings to the default values. I tried examining the request with the fiddler tool. In order for me to be able to capture the traffic from `localhost` with fiddler, I added a period to the address: `http://localhost.:3157/`. So now the error occurs only when I use `http://localhost.:3157/` (with period) and it works normally when I use `http://localhost:3157/` (without period). I additionally tested the behavior in *Chrome, Opera and Safari* -- the ajax link works normally in these browsers. Note that I can get it working normally in IE8 when I attach a query parameter to the ajax link like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new { controller = "Home", param = "param" }, new { id = "myLink" } )
```

I don't really want to do this. I'm running low on ideas here. I'm probably missing something that is blatantly obvious to a seasoned web developer =] Anybody recognize these symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method instead of .click():

```
$('#myLink').live('click', function () {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

because you are replacing the DOM in the AJAX callback (the #main) which contains the link so you are killing the event handler you have assigned.

Also you have a typo in the jquery script inclusion in the `<head>`. You are missing a closing `>` after `type="text/javascript"`:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So here's a complete working example:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="main">@RenderBody()</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "partial";
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "full";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myLink').click(function () {
            $.post(this.href, function (result) {
                $('#main').html(result);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

HomeController index. @ViewBag.Message
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { id = "myLink" } )
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice. I will use the '.live()' function, though it doesn't correct the behavior of the ajax link in IE8. Sorry about the typo, it must have slipped in during editing the question.

Comment: @ghopro, the example I posted works perfectly fine in IE8. At least on my machine :-)

Comment: The working example you posted is the same as my original example except for the typo and the omission of the alert and commented out code in the jquery function. So I assumed it had something to do with the configuration of my specific IE8 instance. I restored the original default settings of IE8 and now it works! I don't know what kind of setting caused this though.. Thx for your time and help!!

Answer (score 0):

add

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    }
});
```

to make sure the correct header is attached.

Comment: Where exactly do I add this? I tried adding it in between the script tags just before the existing function, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: jQuery already sends this header and adding it is not necessary.